# await is a reserved word on fetch request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to make fetch request yet not working. Here is my work

Client side:

```
this.state= {
   from: "from@email.com",
   to: "to@email.com",
   subject: "mainSubject",
   message: "main message",
}

handeSendRequest(){

   await fetch('/api/sendIt', {method:'post', headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/json' }}, body: JSON.stringify(this.state)){

    }

}
render(){
  return(
    <Button onClick={this.handeSendRequest} > Send it </Button>
   )

 }
```

email-util.js

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')(mailGunConfig);


var data = {
  from: req.body.from,
  to: req.body.to,
  subject: req.body.subject,
  text: req,body.text
}

mailgun.message().send(data,function(error, body){
  if(error){
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(body)
  }

}  )
```

server.js

```
const app = express();

const emailUtil = require('./email-util');

app.use('/api/sendIt', emailUtil);
```

I'm new to work on both front end and back end and stuck on this issue. The error I am getting is `await is a reserved word`

Comment: Your email-util.js needs to be a modular route handler. Check the **express.Router** section at the very bottom [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). You need `router.post('/', ...)` since you're sending a POST request. (and remove the `await` for now, since you aren't doing anything after sending the request anyway)

Comment: You must mark your function as `async` to use `await`. The trailing curly brace is also a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

await only works in an async function. You can change your fetch request to to following:

```
    async handeSendRequest(){
       let response= await fetch('/api/sendIt', {method:'post', headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/json' }}, body: JSON.stringify(this.state));
       let result=await response.json();
        console.log(result)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It might just be that handeSendRequest needs to be declared as an **async** function:

```
async handeSendRequest(){
  await fetch('/api/sendIt', {method:'post', headers: {'Content-type' : 'application/json' }}, body: JSON.stringify(this.state))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

await can only be called within an async function, try the following.

```
async handeSendRequest() {
  await fetch...
}
```